# How to PHP loop, finding children categories until no more children, then move to sibling?

Tags: php, loops

**Hello All,
My mind is a bit fryed tyring to figure this one out, and it's been hours. Any help is appreciated!**

I have a set of categories, and their children, which can go on 7 or 8 layers deep. IE:
*---(1) My Categories 

------(2) Marketing (child of 1) 

------(3) HR (child of 1)

--------(4) Job Positions (child of 3)

----------- (6) Temp Jobs (child of 4) 

-----------------(8) New Temp Jobs (child of 6)

----------- (7) Full Time (child of 4) 

-----(5) Operations (child of 1)*

In the DB each folder has a parent_ID as shown above. When I am looping through these folders with a query is there a way to continue the loop to grab the children and continue checking the children for their children, etc until it stops and then moves up to the next parent that was left off?

Right now I have something like:

```
foreach ($firstlevel as $folderid){
echo folder_name($folderid);
$children=children($folderid);////gets the children in an array
     foreach ($children as $childid){
```

However, obviously this will only check the second level. How do I keep this going and going for each children, then check up at the next level to see if there's any more, and then if not, up to the next? Is this even possible? Thank you!

SOME EDITS:
my firstlevel function is just

```
$firstlevel=first_level();
function first_level(){
    $query=mysqli_query(con(),"SELECT category_id from categories where parent IS NULL");
 } ////it spits it out as an array, will save you the semantics
```

and the function that grabs children is the same except

```
function children($folderid){
    $query=mysqli_query(con(),"SELECT category_id from categories where parent='$folderid' ");
 } ////it spits it out as an array as well
```

Comment: Show what you have written in query .

Comment: So, you're trying to do a depth first search?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve the scenerio using regular looping as there's no set limit of the depth.
It is better to do depth search.

Please check with the following function. Provide an iterable tree to it and it will serially go to the leaves of first branch, then the next branch, then next serially.

Yo have not provided details on what type of data structure you are using, so in the example function is for array of objects. You can change the 'is_array' to something else(like - is_iterable) based on your scenerio.

```
fnc_travarse($your_data_nodes);

function fnc_travarse($nodes) {
  foreach ($nodes as $folderid) {
    echo $folderid.'<br />';
    $childs = children($folderid);
    if (!empty($childs) && is_array($childs)) fnc_travarse($childs);
  }
}
```

Comment: You actuslly can solve this with looping. See the 2nd pseudocode [ example on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 1):

This is the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzjHx_6eRyI
And this is the code from the same.

```
    <?php         
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
    // check connection
    if($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed! " . $db->connect_error);
    }

            function categoryTree($parent_id=0, $submark='') {
                global $db;
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=$parent_id ORDER BY catname ASC");

                if($query->num_rows >0) {
                    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()) {                            
                        echo $row['id'] . " $submark " . $row['catname'] . " <br/>";
                        categoryTree($row['id'],$submark." >> ");
                    }
                }

            }                
           echo categoryTree();        

    ?>
```

Database Table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `catname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `parent_id`, `catname`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'My Categories'),
(2, 1, 'Marketing'),
(3, 1, 'HR'),
(4, 3, 'Job Positions'),
(5, 1, 'Operations'),
(6, 4, 'Temp Jobs'),
(7, 6, 'New Temp Jobs'),
(8, 4, 'Full Time Jobs');
```

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote your internet sleuthing or downvote the solution for unnecessarily making db queries in a recursive function... I guess I'll upvote since it is *the* solution...